# How to "separate" image uploads while using multiupload image field

Tags: drupal, slideshow, multi-upload

My client has a bizarre request which is making it difficult to build a slideshow on profile2 pages: The profile2 pages require 4 photos to be uploaded, and he does not believe that the users adding content to the site will "get" the multi-select method found in most file upload modules. The Field Slideshow module only works if you're using multiupload (which of course makes sense), and that's how I had it set up initially - which worked perfectly. I've tried using the field collection module, then creating a Slideshow view, but the image fields in the field collection field aren't being seen as a group. I think I had to select one of the 4 image fields to use instead of all 4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> he does not believe that the users adding content to the site will "get" the multi-select method found in most file upload modules

This hardly makes sense, I guess you tried to explain things to your client ?

Assuming you have several image fields on your content type, you could build a view which create a list (unformatted or HTML list) of these fields, maybe using a global field rewriting (you add all your image fields, exclude them from display, custom their display by removing field wrapper and field+label wrapper (in order to get only ), add a global text field in which you include image fields token), and then create your slideshow in a custom javascript file, using whatever library you like ([Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) is great).

Your global text field would look like :

```
<div class="wrapper cycle-slideshow">
[field_image]
[field_image_1]
...
</div>
```

(with cycle2 adding a cycle-slideshow class will initialize your slideshow)

...but you need [token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) to do so.

I often find it more convenient to setup javascript things like that (slideshows, gmaps...) by myself instead of using views integration.

Hope I understood your issue correctly, good luke with this.

Answer (score 0):

For every (custom) field you have option "Number of values" which you can set to fixed amount (i.e. 4) or unlimited. Can you use that?

Answer (score 0):

Easier: Use Rules. Create an additonal (fifth) image field (multivalued) that will be the one consuming the slideshow. Create a new Rule, triggered on creation or update of your content with 4 actions: each one adding the content of one of the fields to the multivalued field list. You probably need to avoid showing that field but that depends on what are you using to display, so hide it using display suite or just not using it in the content template. This way, you show your users your 4 fields but makes the slideshow work based on a computing of the user inputs.

Comment: I like this idea! I would like to keep using the Field Slideshow formatter, as it's perfect for the simple display that each profile2 page needs. I never thought about using Rules to populate a field, though. Thanks!

Comment: @McTwist glad it helps you and yes, Rules is a great module to involve custom global behaviors to a site... a vote please!

Comment: Any reason why I wouldn't be able to access the profile2's image fields when creating a rule for this? I'm selecting the event, "After saving a new profile," and then as a condition, "Entity has field," choosing either an image field or that 5th containing field, but when attempting to select an action, none of those fields are available to me. What am I missing? I think this is the first time I've incorporated a file into a custom rule.